# Axios error : TypeError: adapter is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios, webextension-polyfill

I'm making a web extension using webextension-polyfill and vuejs (axios for requesting).
I needed to make requests from my content script but it threw my cors errors, so I forwarded thoses requests to the background script. But axios thew me that error :
[axios error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDFwG.png)

here's my manifest :

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Teamlock web extension",
    "description": "Teamlock web extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "/background.js"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "/content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

the way I forwarded the requests to background script :

```js
runtime.sendMessage({method:"GET",endpoint:`/api/v1/workspace`,params:{}})
.then(res =>{
   console.log(res);
});
```

The listener on background script :

```js
import {runtime} from "webextension-polyfill";
runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender) =>{
    console.log("bien reçu");
    return http.get(`/api/v1/workspace`)
})
```

the `http` module uses axios :

```js
import axios from "axios"
import { storage } from "webextension-polyfill";

const service = axios.create()

// request interceptor
service.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
        const {token} = await storage.local.get("token")
        if (token) {
            config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`
        }
        const {instance} = await storage.local.get("instance") 
        config.baseURL = instance;
        return config
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error) // for debug
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)
export default service
```

Do you have any ideas ? I found also this issue on github : https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2968

Comment: `this issue` is with `delete` - where do you have a delete request? in fact, where are you even using axios?

Comment: I have the same result than that issue : executing a request from background script with axios (http module uses axios)

Comment: but ... your code isn't showing HOW you use axios ... saying `the http module uses axios` means naff all ... is the `http module` something you wrote? if so ... show some naffing code

Comment: I modified the post to include the code of the http module